# how to get char casted from int to 'appear' in console out?

Tags: c++, vector, casting, char, integer

I have a vector and want to cast ints to chars, and then pushback the casted char to the vector.
what i am getting is 'invisible' elements in the vector, which cause no obvious errors, increase the vec.size() count, however do not display during console output. how do i fix this so they appear as a normal / 'visible' char in the vector? see code below for demonstration of the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    std::vector<char> test{'a','b'};
    
    int i = 5;
    char h = char(i);
    
    test.push_back(h);
    
    for(auto i: test){
        std::cout << "should be an element ->" << i << '\n';
    }
    std::cout<< "size of vec is -> " << test.size();
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Note that the integer `0` is _not_ equivalent to the character `'0'`. The character with numeric value 0 is the non-printable null-character.

Comment: To "cast" a single digit int to printable character try `char h = i + '0';`.

Comment: @Pyson Declare a vector of the type std::vector<std::string> and use the function std::to_string to convert integers to strings and push them on the vetctor

Comment: Depending on what you want (printing characters or values) you either need to get the correct character code point (see @Yksisarvinen 's comment) *or* cast to (unsigned) int before outputting respectively. Side note: If you want to store values in ranges of either [-128; 127] or [0; 255] you should explicitly use signed or unsigned char respectively, signedness of raw `char` is implementation defined.

Comment: As the others pointed out, it's not really clear what you want to do with this. If you need to 'see' those unprintable characters, I'd suggest something like:

[compilerexplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Mb9sj7jzd)

Comment: thanks all, thinking too much in python i guess, sorry for any confusion @Yksisarvinen, answered my question however that method only works for characters less than 10. i guess its not as easy as to go int i = 100;  str(i) == printable 100 in c++

Comment: The thing is that Python's basic type for characters is `str`, which can store any number of characters. In C++, `char` can only store a single character. For storing multiple, use `std::string`. And you can use `std::to_string(i)` to convert number to string of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions and comments. in order to provide clarity here is what i was trying to acheive.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    std::vector<char> test{'a','b'};
    
    int i = 12345 ;
   
    
    std::string w = std::to_string(i);
    
    for(auto i : w){
        test.push_back(i);
        
    }
    
    for(auto i : test){
        std::cout << "element in the vector -> " <<i << '\n';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if we inspect what you are printing

```
should be an element ->a
should be an element ->b
should be an element ->♣
size of vec is -> 3
```

And the values of those elements in array

```
vec[0] = 'a' (thats 97 integer value)
vec[1] = 'b' (thats 98 integer value)
vec[2] = '\x5' (thats 5 integer value)
```

You are gettings the right output for your program.
If you wish to convert 5 into char, you should add '0' character to it.
So something like

```c
char = i + '0';
```

Would store integer value of 65 or '5' in character.

Note : Characters in C/C++ are just 8 bit numbers and when you print them, you get one of the following characters from ascii table. Some of the characters from ascii table are non printable characters, for example character with value 0 is NULL. TAB is value 8 (also printable as '\t') or ESC being 27.
[image: Ascii table]